# Find employee who made highest sales to the customer who made most purchases

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble with this question in my Database homework And need to answer this question:

**Which employee has the highest sales to the customer who has made the most purchases?**

And these are my database tables
[image]

**And these are my attempts to write this query**

```
--select Customers.Firstname,Products.Name,Sales.Quantity from Customers
--inner join Sales
--on Customers.CustomerId=Sales.CustomerId
--inner join Products
--on Sales.productId=Products.ProductId
--where Products.Name like 'Mobile'


--Select Customers.CustomerId,max(COUNT(Customers.CustomerId)) As Customecount,Emploees.EmploeeId,max(COUNT(Emploees.EmploeeId))as EmploeeeCount from Emploees
--inner join Sales
--on Emploees.EmploeeId=Sales.EmploeeId
--inner join Customers
--on Customers.CustomerId=Sales.CustomerId
--group by Customers.CustomerId,Emploees.EmploeeId            ,Count(Sales.productId)as productCount,Count(Emploees.EmploeeId)as emploeeCount,Count(Customers.CustomerId)as customerCount 

select  * from
(select Distinct Customers.CustomerId,Sales.productId,COUNT(Sales.productId)as CountProduct from Customers
inner join Sales
on Customers.CustomerId=Sales.CustomerId
inner join Emploees
on Emploees.EmploeeId=Sales.EmploeeId
group by Sales.productId,Emploees.EmploeeId,Customers.CustomerId,Sales.productId) as Result
--gr
```

But these don't work

Please, help me to write this Query.

Comment: I know. But this is very confusing. I tried thousands of ways. But it doesn't work

Comment: Ok post your attempt in your question, let's see what you have tried so far.

Comment: I added my efforts,See them. ;-)

Comment: Most purchases by what criteria? By count or by total amount?

Comment: The Main question was not clear. But I think,By count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to solve the problem step by step. Find the customer id with most orders by total:

```
SELECT TOP 1 sales.customerid
FROM sales
JOIN products ON sales.productid = products.productid
GROUP BY sales.customerid
ORDER BY SUM(sales.quantity * products.price) DESC
```

Next step is to find the employee with most sales by count to that customer (changing it to by total is trivial):

```
SELECT TOP 1 sales.salespersonid
FROM sales
WHERE sales.customerid = (
    SELECT TOP 1 sales.customerid
    FROM sales
    JOIN products ON sales.productid = products.productid
    GROUP BY sales.customerid
    ORDER BY SUM(sales.quantity * products.price)
)
GROUP BY sales.salespersonid
ORDER BY COUNT(sales.salesid) DESC
```

Finally select the employee record:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE employeeid = (
    SELECT TOP 1 sales.salespersonid
    FROM sales
    WHERE sales.customerid = (
        SELECT TOP 1 sales.customerid
        FROM sales
        JOIN products ON sales.productid = products.productid
        GROUP BY sales.customerid
        ORDER BY SUM(sales.quantity * products.price)
    )
    GROUP BY sales.salespersonid
    ORDER BY COUNT(sales.salesid) DESC
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this....

First get the customer with most purchases and then find all employees who have sold to that customer and return the top 1 employee with the most sales.

```
SELECT TOP (1)  
          e.EmploeeId
        , SUM(s.quantity * p.Price) TotalSales
FROM        Emploees    e 
inner join  Sales       s ON e.EmploeeId = s.EmploeeId
inner join  Product     p ON s.productId = s.productId
WHERE s.CustomerId = (
                        -- Get the customer with most purchases 
                        SELECT TOP (1) x.CustomerId
                        FROM ( SELECT  
                                      c.CustomerId
                                    , SUM(s.quantity * p.Price) TotalSales
                                FROM        Customers   c 
                                inner join  Sales       s ON c.CustomerId = s.CustomerId
                                inner join  Product     p ON s.productId = o.productId
                                GROUP BY c.CustomerId
                             ) x
                        ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
                     )
GROUP BY e.EmploeeId
ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
```

To find Most Sales and Purchases by count (Number of sales/Purchases) following query will do the trick:

```
SELECT TOP (1)  
          e.EmploeeId
        , COUNT(*) TotalSales
FROM        Emploees    e 
inner join  Sales       s ON e.EmploeeId = s.EmploeeId
WHERE s.CustomerId = (

                        SELECT TOP (1) x.CustomerId
                        FROM ( SELECT  
                                      c.CustomerId
                                    , COUNT(*) TotalSales
                                FROM        Customers   c 
                                inner join  Sales       s ON c.CustomerId = s.CustomerId
                                GROUP BY c.CustomerId
                             ) x
                        ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
                     )
GROUP BY e.EmploeeId
ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments you said that "most sales" mean more sale quantity. This answer takes this criteria into consideration.

```
SELECT TOP (1)  SalesPersonID,
                (FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) AS EmployeeName
FROM            Sales       S
JOIN            Employees   E       ON      S.SalesPersonID  =  E.EmployeeID
WHERE           CustomerID = 

(
-- Sub-query that returnes CustomerID with most quantities bought 
SELECT TOP (1)      CustomerID
FROM                Sales
GROUP BY            CustomerID
ORDER BY            SUM(Quantity)       DESC
)

GROUP BY        SalesPersonID,
                (FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName)
ORDER BY        SUM(Quantity)
```